# How to put two HTML buttons on both sides and on the same level (row)? Or if there are errors, how can I find them?

Tags: html, css

Here is the HTML code of the buttons:

```
{% extends 'main/layout.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="features">
        <h1>Главная страница</h1>
        <div style="display: inline-block;" id="outer">
            <form action="{% url 'about' %}">
                <button class="btn btn-warning">На страницу про нас</button>
            </form>
            <form action="{% url 'data' %}">
                <button class="btn btn-warning">На страницу данных</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block title %}Главная страница{% endblock %}
```

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: use   "display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;" instead "display: inline-block;"

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by working with flex box, the space-between will space them out to the far edges:

```
.button-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: if this does not work also try this code :<div class="features">
  <h1>Главная страница</h1>
  <div class="button-container">
    <form action="{% url 'about' %}">
      <button class="btn btn-warning">На страницу про нас</button>
    </form>
    <form action="{% url 'data' %}">
      <button class="btn btn-warning">На страницу данных</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To address styling issues, start with the HTML and any styling you have:

```html
<div class="features">
    <h1>Главная страница</h1>
    <div style="display: inline-block;" id="outer">
        <form action="about">
            <button class="btn btn-warning">На страницу про нас</button>
        </form>
        <form action="data">
            <button class="btn btn-warning">На страницу данных</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Use your browser's debugging tools to observe the styling rules being applied to your elements.  In this case, the `<div>` with `id="outer"` is `inline-block`, so it doesn't take up the full width.  Remove that and see that happens (still in your browser's debugging tools):

```html
<div class="features">
    <h1>Главная страница</h1>
    <div id="outer">
        <form action="about">
            <button class="btn btn-warning">На страницу про нас</button>
        </form>
        <form action="data">
            <button class="btn btn-warning">На страницу данных</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now that `<div>` takes up the full width, but so do the `<form>` elements.  You can make *those* be `inline-block`:

```html
<div class="features">
    <h1>Главная страница</h1>
    <div id="outer">
        <form style="display: inline-block;" action="about">
            <button class="btn btn-warning">На страницу про нас</button>
        </form>
        <form style="display: inline-block;" action="data">
            <button class="btn btn-warning">На страницу данных</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which "works".  But you may be able to do better.  You can do a lot of things with [CSS `flex`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).  For example, that `<div>` can be a flex container:

```html
<div class="features">
    <h1>Главная страница</h1>
    <div style="display:flex;" id="outer">
        <form action="about">
            <button class="btn btn-warning">На страницу про нас</button>
        </form>
        <form action="data">
            <button class="btn btn-warning">На страницу данных</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you can do what you like with that `flex` styling.  Do you just want a `gap` between the `<form>` elements?  Do you want them to take up the full width with maximum space between?  Something else?  There are lots of options available.  For a simple gap, for example:

```html
<div class="features">
    <h1>Главная страница</h1>
    <div style="display:flex;gap:1rem;" id="outer">
        <form action="about">
            <button class="btn btn-warning">На страницу про нас</button>
        </form>
        <form action="data">
            <button class="btn btn-warning">На страницу данных</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or for full-width space:

```html
<div class="features">
    <h1>Главная страница</h1>
    <div style="display:flex;justify-content:space-between;" id="outer">
        <form action="about">
            <button class="btn btn-warning">На страницу про нас</button>
        </form>
        <form action="data">
            <button class="btn btn-warning">На страницу данных</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```